# htaccess rewrite rule for changing html and htm extensions to php

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am changing a website that has some pages ending with .htm and some pages ending with .html into php.

All site names, folders and structures remain the same and only the extension will change from .htm and .html to .php.

What would be the correct rewrite rule for the .htaccess file be in this regards?

After some research I came up with the following and want to make sure that this would be correct:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).htm /$1.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html /$1.php [R=301,L]
```

Would above code in the .htaccess file be correct and is there something else I would have to include?

Comment: The other option is to parse `.htm` and `.html` files as PHP and don't bother changing the file extension thus avoiding the redirect.

Answer (score 2):

Your rules look fine, but you will have to turn the rewrite engine ON first..

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Then add your rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm /$1.php [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html /$1.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: These two rules should be combined into one (ie. `^(.*)\.html?$`) and don't forget to escape the literal dot. The `RewriteBase` directive is not required here.